# How to run tests sequentially in Testcafe one browser?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to see a better way to run tests sequentially in Testcafe one browser, I have more than 30 tests.

Currently I'm using numbers for each test:

1. List item

   - test1register.ts,

     - test2login.ts,

Comment: Welcome. What is your question? Please edit your question.

Comment: When I run tests using testcaferc.json, I need to run the tests in specific order but now when I created the test files it's running based on testnames order!

Comment: Test cases should be independent, so the order in which they are run does not matter. Consider changing the test cases and their steps, rather then trying to figure out how to run them in a specific order.

Comment: I understand test cases should be independent and I almost try to make them in a way possible also I don't want to keep all at one place I want to divide according to names! so please let me know if there is any better way I can run them the order I want?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the directory in command line, it will run tests sequentially.

```
testcafe chrome ./tests/
```